# Oracle db connection using hikaricp java

Tags: java, oracle, hikaricp

I'm trying to create a connection pool for Oracle database using hikaricp and java..

Here is my below code..

```
public class OracleCon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            Connection con = dataSource().getConnection();
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    private static DataSource dataSource() {
        final HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
        ds.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
        ds.setDataSourceClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", "localhost");
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("port", "5432");
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", "test");
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("user", "user");
        ds.addDataSourceProperty("password", "password");
        return ds;
    }
}
```

and I'm getting below error.

```
09:15:10.627 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - schema................................none
09:15:10.627 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - threadFactory................................internal
09:15:10.627 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - transactionIsolation................................default
09:15:10.627 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - username................................none
09:15:10.627 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - validationTimeout................................5000
09:15:10.627 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver to javax.sql.DataSource
```

Any suggestions would also be helpful.. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `dataSource()` method you are trying to assign the **driver class** to the **data source class** property. Instead of using `setDataSourceClassName()` use the `setDriverClassName()` method.

Here's how your final configuration will looks like -

```
private static DataSource dataSource() {
    final HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
    ds.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
    ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", "localhost");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("port", "5432");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", "test");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("user", "user");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("password", "password");
    return ds;
}
```